# Touchpad stops working after a device is plugged into an USB port

Tags: 18.04, usb, touchpad

Since a few weeks I encounter the strange behaviour that whenever I plug in any device via any available USB port of my Dell Latitude 5480 the touchpads stops working.

If all USB ports are empty it works without any problems.

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I recently changed some settings with respect to the sensitivity of the touchpad. The problem might be related to these changes. Any ideas of how to fix it?

[Edit]

The problem occurs only when a media device is plugged into a USB port and the integrated explorer is opened.

Nobody an idea how to fix it?

Comment: 18.04 LTS is behaving very similarly for me.